# Clarification about opennlp algorithm

Tags: nlp, opennlp

I'm trying to get in with openNlp. I need it to get new organizations(startups) from news websites (for example: techcrunch). I have a model with organizations, which I use to recognize organizations in publications(en-ner-organization). And here I have a question:

> In case there is a publication about new startup, which was born yesterday,
>   will openNlp recognize it as organization?

As far as I understand - no. Until I don't train model with this new startup, right?

If all my assumptions are correct, the model partially contains of organizations names, so if I want my model to recognize new organization, I have to train it with it's name.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, OpenNLP should use a statistical model to address named entity recognition: this means that, if OpenNLP has been properly trained with enough data, it should be able to recognize new startups (it's not a `grep` of known tokens over a file).

Of course metrics such as precision, recall and F1 are useful to determine the accuracy of the algorithm.